# Hassle-free Python IDE for GUI development

Tags: python, ide

I am trying to build a GUI in Python and I'm having trouble setting up a Python environment that "simply works" for the second time now.

Since I'm quite happy with Jetbrains products, all my tries until now were based on PyCharm. The first time, I went with standard Python installations. This time, I was recommended Anaconda, which comes with more packages.

Unfortunately, I still [have problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38706946/480982) getting a simple Hello world program to run.

I'm looking for something that

- installs the IDE
- and Python
- and PIP
- and pkg-config
- and GTK+

and if I understand [this GTK+ page](http://www.gtk.org/download/windows.php) correctly

- installs GLib
- installs cairo
- installs Pango
- installs ATK
- installs gdk-pixbuf

and EVERYTHING ELSE that's needed for serious development.

I don't want to spend wasting several hours of downloading and installing dozens of libraries until I can compile and run a hello world program.

Does such a thing exist or do I need to build it myself (if I figure out how to do it)?

Comment: Your problems are *&not** with PyCharm. You will have them with any IDE. Stick with PyCharm - there is simply nothing better - nothing that even comes close. You ar ehaving pakage management problems, which ar enot hte fault of PyCharm

Answer (score 2):

If you would like an all in one python environment where you get everything in a single download they I would recommend [PythonXY](https://python-xy.github.io/) - on Windows it is a single file to download and install, that includes:

- Python *of course*
- IDE: Spyder
- GUI Libraries:

  - wxPython
  - Qt
  - pyGTK
- A really good selection of libraries.
- The downsides are that it is currently still python 2.x and Windows only

Component Map from website:
[image: Component Map]

Answer (score 1):

You can get a very complete bundle of python, libraries and GUI from Continuum Analytics [Anacoda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads)

- Python (of course) 2.7 **or** 3.5
- Cross Platform - Win/OS-X/Linux
- 720+ of the most popular Python, R & Scala packages for stats, data mining, machine learning, deep learning, simulation & optimization, geospatial, text & NLP, graph & network, image analysis
- Featured packages include: NumPy, SciPy, pandas, scikit-learn, Numba, PyTables, h5py, Matplotlib, Jupyter (formerly IPython), Spyder, Qt/PySide, VTK, Numexpr, Cython, Theano, scikit-image, NLTK, NetworkX, IRKernel, dplyr, shiny, ggplot2, tidyr, caret, nnet
- Software development via multiple IDEs
- Commercial Support available (for a fee)
- Down side is that you get into the habit of using conda rather than pip.

Comment: I am already using Anaconda as stated in the question, but that didn't help much.